# How to make the entire tableview scroll horizontally in swift

Tags: tableview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a TableView with one section and many rows.
Each rows contains many uitextfields which are created programmatically, each one are positioning just to the right to the previous one.

This is like a spreadsheet.

I need to have a scroll horizontally the entire TableView.
currently, I have it only for each row independently.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let largeur = CGFloat(Double(game!.scores.countColumns()) * cellWidth)
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: largeur, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
}
```

What is the code to do this ? and where to put it ?

Comment: I get a similar result that I need by activating the Bounce Horizontally in the storyboard. BUT it's bounce that means the view come back to the origine.

Comment: finally, I create a new view controller with a scroll view and I put the tableview inside. To have the horizontal scroll, In viewWillAppear,         tableView.contentSize.width = largeur; scrollView.contentSize.width = largeur ;
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: largeur, height: tableView.frame.size.height)